# DDL shows 'true/false'; i would like to see 'yes/no' data comes form a table as bool. how can i change the text of the DDL

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a DDL that shows if a task is completed. in the table it is stored as bool, so when it comes out it is true or false. i would like to build my DDL to show yes when true and no when false. does anyone have any hints :) this is what i have so far.

```
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
            (from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = n.COMPLETED.Value.ToString(),
                    Value = n.COMPLETED.Value.ToString(),
                }
            ).Distinct();

        ViewData["COMPLETED"] = items;
```

is there a way to put a conditional statement so that the text will display yes or no depending on the true or false? or how can i make this happen. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select new SelectListItem
{
    Selected = false,
    Text = n.COMPLETED.Value ? "yes" : "no",
    Value = n.COMPLETED.Value,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this has no localization, but is simple

```
Text = n.COMPLETED ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Comment: thanks a bunch i have to do "n.COMPLETED.Value" but that worked perfectly, thanks again

Comment: A year after the post above -- I find my solution :) ! Yeah!

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
            (from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = n.COMPLETED.Value ? "Yes" : "No",
                    Value = n.COMPLETED.Value ? "Yes" : "No",
                }
            ).Distinct();

        ViewData["COMPLETED"] = items;
```